# i am not able to access the properties of object in angluar

Tags: angular

[image: console of shipment returned]i am using getshipment method to get data by id which is return an object and displaying on frontend like this [object Object]. i want to access the details and then display details on frontend

```
export class ShipmentInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  shipment: any[];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private shipmentService: ShipmentService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getShipment();
  }
  getShipment(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(id);
    this.shipmentService
      .getShipment(id)
      .subscribe((shipment) => (this.shipment = shipment));
  }
}
```

my getshipment method in sevices is

```
  getShipment(id: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const shipmentUrl = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<any[]>(shipmentUrl);
  }
```

html component of shipment info.
shipment.id or shipment.name is returning undefined

```
<div class="shipment">
  {{ shipment }}
</div>
```

object data

```
 {
    "id": "S1000",
    "name": "T-shirts(Summer2018) from Shanghai to Hamburg",
    "cargo": [
      {
        "type": "Fabric",
        "description": "1000 Blue T-shirts",
        "volume": "2"
      },
      {
        "type": "Fabric",
        "description": "2000 Green T-shirts",
        "volume": "3"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "sea",
    "type": "FCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Shanghai Port",
    "services": [
      {
        "type": "customs"
      }
    ],
    "total": "1000",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "U1000"
  },
```

Comment: To debug what information you are getting, you can add a `console.log(shipment)` to the anonymous function in the subscription.

Comment: @TrevorKropp i have added image of console data

Comment: The type of the data is an object, not an array. Try declaring the type as `any` instead of `any[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot print object directly, You have to print whatever value you want to print. like below,

If you are receiving array in response, then use below

```
<div class="shipment"  *ngFor="let ship of shipment">
 Name: {{ ship.name }}
 <br>
 Mode: {{ship.mode}}
</div>
```

Otherwise, Change your service method return type array to object like this,

```
getShipment(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const shipmentUrl = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(shipmentUrl);
  }
```

and html code will be like this,

```
<div class="shipment" *ngIf="shipment">
 Name: {{ shipment?.name }}
 <br>
 Mode: {{shipment?.mode}}
</div>
```

You can refer this link from [Angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2)

Comment: i have mentioned that i have tried it and i am getting error of this kind "error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'."

Comment: idashby you are receiving array in response, so you need to use for loop, and then print name and all.